# Is it possible to use Certbot for automating SSL certificates with CAs other than Let's Encrypt?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Is it possible to use `Certbot` for automating the renewal process of the SSL certificates with CAs other than Let's Encrypt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as the CA supports [ACME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Certificate_Management_Environment). [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) and [BuyPass](https://www.buypass.com/ssl/products/acme) offer free certificates with ACME. [DigiCert](https://docs.digicert.com/certificate-tools/Certificate-lifecycle-automation-index/acme-user-guide/) seems to support requesting paid certificates through ACME.

To use this, you need to [pass extra arguments](https://www.xf.is/2020/06/30/list-of-free-acme-ssl-providers/) to certbot, most notably `--server`.