# Certbot on GKE for automating SSL certificates with CAs other than Let's Encrypt

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Is it possible to install `Certbot` on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) for installing and renewing the SSL certificates on Load Balancers (LB) but with CAs other than Let's Encrypt?

Comment: Certbot only works for LE as far as I know

Comment: No it can work with other CAs as well but not sure if this can work on GKE because the certs there are installed on LBs - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/243039/is-it-possible-to-use-certbot-for-automating-ssl-certificates-with-cas-other-tha